# How do I know how much disk space I have?

Tags: disk-management

I'm new to Elementary and Linux in general. Just installed it today. How do I find how much disk space I have and more general information about my hard drive like you can in Windows and Mac OS X? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click Power button at the top-right corner of the screen, then select About This Computer in drop-down menu.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a command line solution try running `df -h` in terminal. Example output on my laptop is below.

```
udev            2.7G   12K  2.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           538M  1.5M  536M   1% /run
/dev/sda6        48G   34G   12G  75% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.7G   70M  2.6G   3% /run/shm
none            100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda5       298G  148G  151G  50% /mnt/storage
/dev/sda2        96M   68M   29M  71% /boot
```

It shows the free disk space for all mounted partitions

Answer (score 1):

I'd second @roman's answer. "About This Computer" is probably the simplest way to get information about your hard drive.

For more detailed information, you could install [Disk Usage Analyzer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/baobab/) or [Disk Utility](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/) from the Software Center. Disk Usage Analyzer is a lot like [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com/) for OS X, and Disk Utility is a lot like OS X's Disk Utility.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think I'll try installing Disk Utility, as I'm most familiar with OS X's Disk Utility.